# Toggling Specific Multiple Bits

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I'm using an `int` flag to keep track of the result of database operations, and had a question about flipping bits. I want to be able to pass a flag (or a few flags) to a method that will toggle those bits. This is the method I'm using now (`flag` is the current flag):

```
private void toggleFlags(int flags) {
    flag = (flag & (flag | (~flag))) ^ flags;
}
```

It looks like it works to me, but I just want to make sure that it is doing what it should be. Can anyone confirm this for me?

Comment: Exactly what is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: If you just want to toggle flags, then flag = (flag ^ flags) is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, your code there is equal to performing just this:

```
flag = flag ^ flags;
```

Which is a plain simple XOR operation which is enough to switch the specific flags you want.

The reason for why it is this easy is that `(flag | (~flag))` just results in a bunch of binary 1s, and then `(flag & <a bunch of binary 1s>)` is of course the same as `flag`. So all that statement is left with is really `flag = flag ^ flags`

Comment: Wow I feel dumb...Thanks!